# Receive an email in SQL Server to add data to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have set up an email account which currently uses the MSDB database which is automatically generated. I've set up emails to be sent from SQL Server which works fine, however I am not receiving the replies into the database, nor a stand alone email sent to the database, it just appears into the email account I am using to send the emails from...

Is anyone able to help me or point me in the right direction so that I can send an email to a SQL Server database to update a file, for an example I will say I want to send a time sheet via email in this format:

```
Monday
08:00
17:00

Tuesday
08:00
17:30
```

If this is stored into the database I know I can read it and then convert it to represent what I want, its just the ability to actually send an email the the SQL Server I am having issues with.

I am using SQL Server 2012 64 bit aswell

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189829%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: im afraid that does not work as im running the 64 bit version.. I am using Database mail aswell

Comment: as the note says - you should never use that functionality anyhow.

Comment: I aren't using that, its something similar to that which can achieve what I am after